# trying to write a list vertically in to a .csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have a connection to the database and I am trying to execute a simple select command and write to a .csv file. This is what I have

```
import pyodbc
import csv

print("Imported pyodbc")
username = "****"
# connection_string = "*Connection_string*" % username
print("Before connection")
# conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
conn = pyodbc.connect("connection string")

print("Connection complete")

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM (tablename) limit 10")

rows = list(cursor.fetchall())
for row in rows:
    print(row)



with open('\\*link*\\test.csv','w', newline='') as out:
    csv_out=csv.writer(out)

    first_elements = [x[0] for x in rows]
    print(first_elements)
    for i in range(len(first_elements)):
        print (first_elements[i])
        temp=first_elements[i]
        csv_out.writerow(temp)
    csv_out.writerow('')
```

each row is a tuple with 204 elements and I am trying to save only the 1st element in .csv file. I tried using `csv.writeout(row[0])` and it gave a error:

```
 csv_out.writerow(row)
_csv.Error: iterable expected, not int
```

I tried to convert in to a list, iterator inside writerow but it gives rows of 1st elements

```
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
```

but what I want is

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand your format, but if you get an `int` error then try to put your int in a list: `csv_out.writerow([row])`

Comment: try `csv_out.writerow([row])` ; a list is iteratable, an int is not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `first_elements = [[x[0]] for x in rows]` to create iterable elements which represents rows instead of an integer.

Edit: Also as Jean mentioned in the comments, you can `csv.out.writerow([row])` as an alternate solution.

Comment: This solution worked, thank you! But I don't quite understand what happened there. {[[x[0]] for x in rows]} vs {[x[0] for x in rows]}. The first one is a list of lists? vs the second one being a list of ints? Why didnt the second one work?

Comment: Well, the `csv.out.writerow` function expects an iterable for the row, as csv rows usually have more than one value. So when it tried to call the `__iter__` property of the object you passed into the function, which in this case was an int, it threw an error. By using a list, or another iterable (tuple, set, ...) it can iterate over the values you passed in and write them to a file with the delimiter you set (or so I'm assuming)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now. Thank you @Have_Mercy